# Selecting the Parent of the Parent element. Tables/Watir/Ruby

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir

Hey i am trying to select the parent of the parent element i suppose. I have a table in which i am trying to use Watir/Ruby to select the edit or delete button from the same row but in a different coloumn, example.

Name 1      -> Edit Icon -> Delete Icon

Name 2      -> Edit Icon -> Delete Icon

Example code below:

```
<html>
 <body>
     <table class="table-responsive">
         <thead>...</thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>
                     <td class="col-name">Name 1</td>
                     <td> 
                         <a class="edit" href="/">
                             <span class="icon-edit"></span>
                         </a>
                         <a class="delete" href="/">
                             <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                         </a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td class="col-name">Name 2</td>
                     <td> 
                         <a class="edit" href="/">
                             <span class="icon-edit"></span>
                         </a>
                         <a class="delete" href="/">
                             <span class="icon-delete"></span>
                         </a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     ...
                 </tr>
         <tbody>
     </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

So far i have tried this but it is not working. I get an error *TypeError: can't convert Hash into an exact number*

```
  table = @browser.table.when_present(:class => "table-responsive")
    iconrow = table.span(:text => "Name 1").parent
    if iconrow.a(:class => "edit").exists?
      iconrow.a(:class => "edit").click
    end
```

Comment: Be careful with conditionals based on element existence, they often get tricky. Your test should know whether or not an edit button should be clicked at the beginning, and choose the correct method without a conditional based on what is needed. It makes the required watir code more clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a couple issues with the code:
* The :class locator is being applied to `when_present` rather than the table itself. 
* The element with "Name 1" is a `td` rather than a `span`.

Try:

```
table = @browser.table(:class => "table-responsive").when_present
iconrow = table.td(:text => "Name 1").parent
if iconrow.a(:class => "edit").exists?
  iconrow.a(:class => "edit").click
end
```

Comment: I see, figured since it was in a span. Thanks